# yii2 data to the db saves them all null

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii-form

hello guys I have a problem when I send the form data in the database , all NULL fields are saved . Any suggestions?
**my Controller**

```html
public function actionOffri()
   {
    $model = new Offri;

   if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate() && $model->save())
       {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Hai inserito i dati correttamente');
        return $this->render('offri', ['model' => $model]);
       }
}
```

my Model I just added the rules and variables of the fields feature
ex.

```html
public $name;
public function rules()
    {
        return [['name'],'string'.....
                 ....
               ];
}
```

**My Full Model**

```html
class Offri extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'viaggio';
    }

public $data_par;
public $ora_part;
public $data_arrivo;
public $ora_arrivo;
public $citta_part;
public $citta_arrivo;
public $wifi;
public $bagno;
public $ac_dc;
public $condizioni;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['citta_part','citta_arrivo'], 'required'],
            [['citta_part','citta_arrivo'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['posti_disponibili', 'conferma_utenze', 'accounts_id_account', 'posti_max', 'wifi', 'bagno', 'ac_dc'], 'integer'],
            [['prezzo'], 'number'],
            [['accounts_id_account'], 'required'],
            [['citta_part', 'via_part', 'citta_arrivo', 'via_arrivo', 'veicolo'], 'string', 'max' => 45],
            [['note'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['accounts_id_account'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Accounts::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['accounts_id_account' => 'id_account']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id_viaggio' => Yii::t('app', 'Id Viaggio'),
            'citta_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Citta Part'),
            'via_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Via Part'),
            'ora_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Ora Part'),
            'data_part' => Yii::t('app', 'Data Part'),
            'posti_disponibili' => Yii::t('app', 'Posti Disponibili'),
            'conferma_utenze' => Yii::t('app', 'Conferma Utenze'),
            'prezzo' => Yii::t('app', 'Prezzo'),
            'note' => Yii::t('app', 'Note'),
            'accounts_id_account' => Yii::t('app', 'Accounts Id Account'),
            'citta_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Citta Arrivo'),
            'data_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Data Arrivo'),
            'ora_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Ora Arrivo'),
            'via_arrivo' => Yii::t('app', 'Via Arrivo'),
            'veicolo' => Yii::t('app', 'Veicolo'),
            'posti_max' => Yii::t('app', 'Posti Max'),
            'wifi' => Yii::t('app', 'Wifi'),
            'bagno' => Yii::t('app', 'Bagno'),
            'ac_dc' => Yii::t('app', 'Ac Dc'),
        ];
    }
```

Comment: show all the Offri model  code please

Comment: How about your view file? And does your DB table has default value as NULL set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see from your **rules**, **labels** and **members**, it is probably because you're using **virtual** members where you shouldn't. Note that using virtual members will overwrite any value from user's input. Since you're not assigning any manual value, Yii just clears all and leaves them empty. You also most likely have set `null` as default value in your columns (if data is empty), that's why you're seeing `null` in every row.

To solve this issue, remove these lines from your **Model**:

```
public $data_par;
public $ora_part;
public $data_arrivo;
public $ora_arrivo;
public $citta_part;
public $citta_arrivo;
public $wifi;
public $bagno;
public $ac_dc;
public $condizioni;
```

These virtual attributes are being used differently from DB attributes and I think in your case you don't need them here.

Comment: I am still a beginner in yii2 , thanks a lot I have solved .